How can I redirect a Flutter web application to https?
Ok I created my first web application with Flutter, setup SSL and have a domain with two flavours.
http://example.com and
https://example.com setup on IIS.
How can I redirect http to https with Flutter?
I could create Url rewrite server side but I would love to do via Flutter.
Is there such a configuration available?

Do you think that only formatting the url string could be work? Like if you receive hhtp format it to https and if not exist return an error.

The SSL redirection should be setup on your DNS and Hosting service rather than in Flutter web implementation or any Web implementation for that matter. Please check with your DNS provider and Hosting provider on SSL certificate installation and enabling SSL redirection.

Since the server is IIS I a added the following web.config to handle the https redirection by using the Rewrite Module
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

